# Angular http get wrong datatype of Date property

Tags: angular7

I use Angular 7 and Net Core Web API. 
 
In web API I have an employee class with birthday property :

`public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }`

And in Angular:

```
export class Employee {
   public birthday : Date; 
   ... 
}
```

When I call this code:

```
this.http.get<Employee>(url).subscribe(employee => {

  console.log(employee.birthday) 
  console.log(employee.birthday.constructor.name)

});
```

The result is:

> 1995-07-22T00:00:00
>   String

The property is Date, why it constructor name is String?

How can i get correct datatype?

Thank you.

Comment: Because you're not dealing with an `Employee` class object. You're dealing with the JSON object that was returned from your AJAX call. Casting to `<Employee>` does not automatically instantiate an `Employee` object. It just makes your compiler believe it does.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create `Employee` object in from response like this:

```
this.http.get<Employee>(url).subscribe(employee => { 
 const emp = new Employee(employee.birthday);
});
```

Also have to write `constructor` for Employee class.